# How to push to History in React Router v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, history

Is it possible to create a global history file to manage the createBrowserHistory() on react-router-dom v5?
I know the V5 has the useHistory() as a way to get the history. But is it possible to retrieve the history from anywhere, like for cases where I am not using a function component?

On V4 I could create a file history.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

It works on V4
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v4-nfwr0

It doesn't work on V5 - It updates the URL but redirects to not-found
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-not-working-jlrep

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the doc says you should use the v4 of history to work on react-router v5.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history

> Documentation for version 4 can be found on the v4 branch. Version 4 is used in React Router versions 4 and 5.

Comment: Oh! That works for the history/location, too bad there is nothing about how to make the React Router actually notice the change. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing this.See what i done

### Create a file like before

This is the code

```
import {createBrowserHistory}  from 'history';
import store from 'store';
export default createBrowserHistory({
    basename:  store ? store.getState().productionBaseUrl : ''
});
```

The reason why i import Redux is the project does not pulish on nginx root folder.So i should add a basename.If you do not neet it,you can remove it.

Then you can use it in your own coponnet. How to use? Let me show your the code.

```
// if my history in src/router/
import history from 'router/history';

history.push(`${your router address}`)
```

### Attention

The history's push method can pass an object like the origin props.But it's refresh when in the child router always. So pass a string when use it.